# Numpy creating logical array in the presence of NaNs

Tags: numpy

I have an array `x`, from which I would like to extract a logical mask. `x` contains `nan` values, and the mask operation raises a warning, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0, 1], [2.0, np.nan]])
mask = np.isfinite(x) & (x > 0)
```

The resulting mask is correct (`array([[False,  True], [ True, False]], dtype=bool)`), but a warning is raised:

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
```

How can I construct the mask in a way that avoids comparing against NaNs? I am not trying to suppress the warning (which I know how to do).

Comment: Is the result returned by `np.isfinite(x) & (x > 0)` not the answer you are looking for? If not what is the desired result? Or are you looking for a short-circuiting version of `&`?

Comment: @unutbu. The resulting mask is correct. A short-circuiting version of `&` is basically what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do it in two steps - Create the mask of finite ones and then use the same mask to index into itself and also to select the valid mask of remaining finite elements off `x` for testing and setting into the remaining elements in that mask. So, we would have an implementation like so -

```
In [35]: x
Out[35]: 
array([[  0.,   1.],
       [  2.,  nan]])

In [36]: mask = np.isfinite(x)

In [37]: mask[mask] = x[mask]>0

In [38]: mask
Out[38]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Very simple and crafty. Thank you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was afraid it looked crazy enough to use a mask to index into itself, a snake eating its own tail sorta or at least grabbing it ;)

Comment: Yes. It certainly has that appeal.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like masked arrays works with this case:

```
In [214]: x = np.array([[0, 1], [2.0, np.nan]])
In [215]: xm = np.ma.masked_invalid(x)
In [216]: xm
Out[216]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[0.0 1.0]
 [2.0 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [False  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

In [217]: xm>0
Out[217]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[False True]
 [True --]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [False  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
In [218]: _.data
Out[218]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

But other than propagating the masking I don't know how it handles element by element operations like this.  The usual `fill` and `compressed` steps don't seem relevant.

Comment: This seems like a more complicated way to do what @Divakar suggested.